# accessing to an object depending on given parameter

Tags: angular, typescript, object

I want to translate texts with Angular Pipe.

**component.html**

```
<div> {{ 'save' | translate : 'fr'}}  </div>
```

_

**translate.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { findIndex } from 'rxjs';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate'
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
    //some other irrelevant code  
    dictionaryFr = 
        {
          user :"utilisateur",
          save : "enregistrer",
        }      
            
      transform(text: string, lang: string): string{
    
        if (lang=="fr") return this.dictionaryFr[text]; //Does not work
  
      }
```

**error message**

```
   Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ user: string; save: string; }'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ user: string; save: string; }
```

Assumed, I get the text "save" as parameter. I would expect, that above code accesses to dictionaryEn.user and returns "enregistrer". Unfortunately that doesn't work.
Why I cannot replace *this.dictionaryEn[**'user'**]* with *this.dictionaryEn[**text**]*, since "text" has as value "user".

How can I access to the dictionary depending on which text I get as parameter?

Comment: Huh? Why, if you get `"save"` as a parameter, would the code access `dictionaryEn.user`? Especially since `dictionaryEn` is not defined. Please [edit] your question to show a [mre].

Comment: Can you confirm your angular pipe name is "translate" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a simple type issue, please refer the below code. I have defined the type where the object key will be a string and the value will also be a string!

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'translate',
})
export class TranslatePipe implements PipeTransform {
  //some other irrelevant code
  dictionaryFr: { [key: string]: string } = {
    user: 'utilisateur',
    save: 'enregistrer',
  };

  transform(text: string, lang: string): string {
    if (lang == 'fr') return this.dictionaryFr[text]; //Does not work
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bxyzvp)